# "initialization from incompatible pointer type" warning. I could not understand the reason

Tags: c, class, inheritance, struct, polymorphism

I'm trying to imitate polymorphism in the c language. my code works the way I want, but I get a warning: "initialization from incompatible pointer type"
my codes are as follows:

```
//super class:

struct vTable;                  //decleration

typedef struct keypad{
    
    struct vTable const* vptr; 
    uint8_t bsmkSayi;
    
}keypad;

struct vTable{                  //definiton
    void(*keyPadRst)(const keypad* const obj);
    void(*tusla)(const keypad* const obj,uint8_t value);
};
```

//sub class (.h):

```
typedef struct keyKontorPsw{
    keypad super;
}keyKontorPsw;

void ctor_keyKontorPsw(keyKontorPsw* obj,uint8_t basamak);
```

I want keyKontorPsw class to override the methods of the keypad class:

```
//subclass (.c):
void resetKontorPsw(void* obj);
void tuslaKontorPsw(void* obj,uint8_t value);

void ctor_keyKontorPsw(keyKontorPsw* obj,uint8_t basamak){
    static const struct vTable vtbl = {&resetKontorPsw,&tuslaKontorPsw};    //Warning line !!! 
    ctor_keypad(&obj->super,basamak);
    obj->super.vptr = &vtbl;    
}

void resetKontorPsw(void* obj){
    //keyKontorPsw* obj_ = (keyKontorPsw*)obj;
    
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){password_buffer[i]=0;} //bunu da her ihtimale binaen sıfırladım.
    seciliKeyPad    = KEY_KNTR_PSW;
    iterasyon       = 0;
    pswDelIter      = 0;
}

void tuslaKontorPsw(void* obj,uint8_t value){
    keyKontorPsw* obj_ = (keyKontorPsw*)obj;
    
    if(iterasyon< obj_->super.bsmkSayi){//ama tus takımında işlemden sonra ++ olduğu için değeri sınırladıktan sonra 9 oluyor.(silme fonksiyonunda bunu dikkate almam lazım)
        password_buffer[iterasyon] = value;
        printValue(kordntPsw_x[iterasyon],GIR_PSW_Y,size3_black,value,1);
    }
}
```

I get a warning right on this line:
"static const struct vTable vtbl = {&resetKontorPsw,&tuslaKontorPsw};"

I have derived many classes such as "keyKontorPsw" from the "keypad" class. I am getting a warning right on this line in the constructors of all classes. but my code is running successfully. Why does this warning occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the declaration of `vTable` (which you're going to fill up):

```
void (*keyPadRst)(const keypad* const obj);
void (*tusla)(const keypad* const obj, uint8_t value);
```

And due to this syntax where you're getting the warning:

```
static const struct vTable vtbl = {&resetKontorPsw, &tuslaKontorPsw};
```

The parameters of `keyPadRst` and `tusla` in `vTable` is:

```
void(*keyPadRst)(const keypad* const obj);
void(*tusla)(const keypad* const obj, uint8_t value);
```

Which are mismatching since the parameters held by the function `resetKontorPsw` & `tuslaKontorPsw` is:

```
void resetKontorPsw(void* obj); // mismatch with vTable
void tuslaKontorPsw(void* obj, uint8_t value); // mismatch with vTable
```

If you change the function declaration of `resetKontorPsw` & `tuslaKontorPsw` as follows:

```
void resetKontorPsw(const keypad* const obj); // same as vTable's 1st function
void tuslaKontorPsw(const keypad* const obj, uint8_t value); // same as vTable's 2nd function
```

You'll no more get warning then.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a warning right on this line:
> static const struct vTable vtbl ={&resetKontorPsw,&tuslaKontorPsw};"

Given your `vTable` definition:

```
struct vTable{                  //definiton
    void(*keyPadRst)(const keypad* const obj);
    void(*tusla)(const keypad* const obj,uint8_t value);
};
```

The functions `resetKontorPsw` and `tuslaKontorPsw` differ in the arguments type. Basically, `const keypad* const obj` isn't compatible with `void*` and thus the function types become incompatible, too.

[6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15):

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
> return types.146) Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are
> present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the
> ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible
> types. [..]

Assignment between `void*` and any other pointer is likely to work in practice on most platforms, so it "works". But this results in a *constraint violation*. So you should change either the parameter types in those function definitions or the `struct vTable` to match.

Changing `struct vTable` to:

```
struct vTable{                  //definiton
    void(*keyPadRst)(const void* const obj);
    void(*tusla)(const void* const obj,uint8_t value);
};
```

may be the way to go since `void*` - the generic data pointer - is compatible with any type of data pointer (you can pass without casts) and reassign to the right type in the functions.